# Removing JSONB jsonobject from jsonarray in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a jsonb column which contains an ordered array of elements.
I am trying to delete an element based on two identifiers (id + type).

```
CREATE TABLE boards( 
 id          int,
  /* order_json: representing the order of different items under this board  
   (referencing 2 different types/tables */
  order_json  jsonb
 )
```

Example for `order_json` :

`[{"id": 1, "type": 0}, {"id": 1, "type": 1}, {"id": 2, "type": 1}]`

As seen here, there are two elements with id=1 but they're from different tables(types).

I tried doing an update simply with : `json = json - '{"id": 1, "type": 0}'` but this doesn't work.

I also tried with `jsonb_path_query_array` while comparing id and type to what I need, but to no avail.

```
UPDATE boards 
SET order_json = jsonb_path_query_array(order_json, '$ ? (@.id != 1 && @.type != 1)')
WHERE id = ..;
```

**EDIT:**
Some option I put together, which seems to work but Im not sure whether it really does:

```
UPDATE boards b
SET    order_json = 
        (
        SELECT jsonb_agg(element)
        FROM   boards, jsonb_array_elements(order_json) element
        WHERE  (element ->> 'id' != '1' OR element ->> 'type' != '1')
        AND id = 12
        )
WHERE id = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `#-` operator to delete the whole json key value pair in an jsonb array.
Here is the first key value of the jsonb array.

then just `select order_json #-'{1}' from boards;`

But How do I know the queried key value pair is the first indice of the jsonb array.
we can use window function to figure it out.

```
with cte as (
select (jsonb_array_elements(order_json)) splits,
       (jsonb_array_elements(order_json))['id']::int id,
       (jsonb_array_elements(order_json))['type']::text type
from boards)
select *, row_number() over (order by 1) from cte where id = 1 and type = '0';
```

It will return

```
        splits        | id | type | row_number         
----------------------+----+------+------------
 {"id": 1, "type": 0} |  1 | 0    |          1
```

Comment: thank you , is there a way to not use CTE ? 
I'm worried about the performance implications , if there is a more performant way to achieve it

Comment: You need locate the key value pair indices, not just query if it contain key value pair or not. I doubt any index will be have huge gain. about CTE performance, I think the problem is fixed. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#id-1.5.6.12.7

Comment: And what do you think of this option (just something I put together and it seems to work) :
`UPDATE boards b
SET    order_json = 
  (
  SELECT jsonb_agg(element)
  FROM   boards, jsonb_array_elements(order_json) element
  WHERE  (element ->> 'id' != '1' OR element ->> 'type' != '1')
  AND id = 12
  )
WHERE id = 12`

Do you it would be more efficient? Or does it have a bug that I missed?

Comment: I edited the post with this solution above that I wrote in the prevous comment, so it would be more readable than reading here in the comments.
Can you share your thoughts on it please?
And if it's still better to use your solution with cte ?

Comment: Overall I think your idea would be better. I tend to more like use table  query way to solve the problem.